# Can we create a csv file using vb.net with desired number of columns?

Tags: vb.net, csv

I am using this method to create a csv file using vb.net.

```
 protected void btnExportCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.csv");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";

    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        //add separator
        sb.Append(GridView1.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');
    }
    //append new line
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            //add separator
            sb.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text + ',');
        }
        //append new line
        sb.Append("\r\n");
    }
    Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

This code is creating csv file. But i dont want any extra column in csv.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course!

```
  ...
  for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count - 1; k++)
  {
    //add separator
     sb.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text + ',');
  }
  //add final element
  sb.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[GridView1.Columns.Count - 1].Text );
  //append new line
  sb.Append("\r\n");
  ...
```

Comment: your code is also giving so many column in csv file. I want only four columns in csv.